# Button not sending POST request to update object django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a scheduling app with Event objects and I'm trying to create a form that will allow the user to update an Event that already exists by the press of the button. However, when the user presses the button it doesn't seem to do anything. It just refreshes the page.

```
 {% for a in availability %}
                      <form method='POST'>
                      <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'updateevent' a.id %}" type="submit" role="button">{{a.day}}: {{a.start_time}} - {{a.end_time}}</a></li>
                      </form>
                      {% endfor %}
```

view.py:

```
def updateevent(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            form = EventForm(data=request.POST, instance=post)
            updatedEvent = form.save(commit=False)
            updatedEvent.requester_user = request.user
            updatedEvent.notes = None
            updatedEvent.save()

            return redirect('/')

        except ValueError:
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, 'events/createevent.html', {'form':EventForm(), 'error':'There was an error. Please make sure you entered everything correctly!'})
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

I want the user that presses the button to become the "requester_user", a blank field in my Event object. How can I make this happen?

Comment: a tag fires a get request.

Comment: An `a` tag stays a link even if it looks like a button because of CSS. Use an `input` tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor tag triggers GET request. You should use `<button type="submit"></button>` or `<input type="submit">` for POST request.